# Organize Functional Test in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter to create an functional automation suite for our application under test (Right now this is only tool that i can think of which supports interaction with Active MQ , Database , Rest and SOAP API both which are our needs)

Down the line i will be having different test set and configuration files for the application under test.

Below is the process that i will follow to test:

1 Stop the application
2 Load a particular file
3 Start the application 
4 Run the test test that match the loaded config

REPEAT THE SAME FOR OTHER CONFIGURATION.

Now every Test case comes with steps  , liked.
1) Call a Rest API
2) Call a Rest API
3) Call DB
4) Validate the result from step 2

See the attached image for more details on how my i test case is organized.

Problem :

When the report is generated it is not generated on the thread group level but in sampler level , i.e. in the report i have lines , and there is no way to distinguish which TC (Or thread group) and Test Set they belong.

Can someone please suggest how do i achieve this ?

Please consider this is mind :

1 ) Down the line i will have multiple Test Set
2 ) I will also need to merge all this reports from multiple Test Set and create 1 single report that provides a clear picture of what failed / passed and probably the error message received.

Existing Report :

timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1565180794011,2067,DeactiveExistingActiveScenario,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to localhost:1 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect",TC1_Probe_MbaWmcOutboundHappyFlowScenario 1-1,text,false,Test failed: code expected to contain /200/,2738,0,1,1,http://localhost:1/XXX/XXX/XXXX,0,0,2067
1565180796093,2007,ActiveMbaWmcOutboundHappyFlowScenario,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,"Non HTTP response message: Connect to localhost:1 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect",parallel bzm - Parallel Controller,text,false,Test failed: text expected to contain /All 25 invocations validated successful./,3104,0,2,1,http://localhost:1/XXX/XXX/XXX?awaitSeconds=30,0,0,2007
1565180796092,2479,Call DB Procedure,200,OK,parallel bzm - Parallel Controller,text,true,,42,0,1,1,null,2478,0,390

Actual expected :

Probably the same report in a different format like

Test Set 1 :
     TC1   :
        Step 1:
        Step 2:
        Step 3:
    TC2   :
        Step 1:
        Step 2:
        Step 3:

Current Test Set Structure :

https://ibb.co/F4SVHxq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approach, i can think of:

1. Use transaction controller. Put all request of one test under 1 transaction controller. It will be shown in the report at the end. So, first steps then test case name at the end as shown below:-
   [image]
2. Use dummy sampler for test set to produce the extra label as shown below:-
   [image]
   Here TC1 and TC2 are dummy sampler. Based on the above, you can use Test set and test cases labels according to your need. Test Set1--dummy, TC1--dummy,Step 1, Step 2 so on.

Considering, functional test with 1 thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you , will explore this option in next 2 days and share my feedback.

Comment: Used the transaction controller and now its looks ok , thank you sunny_teo.

Comment: Glad to hear that..Please check the link to help others  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers